# iOS Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

Several questions have already been posted on StackOverflow regarding this problem and I've read many of them but the posted solutions haven't been able to resolve my problem.

I simply want to have a fixed margin or padding of 4 pixels between a superview and its subview. As the superview is resized, the subview must be automatically resized so that a constant 4 pixel padding remains on all sides.

I initially tried doing this in Interface Builder in a separate XIB file for the class in question and I kept receiving the notification of conflicting constraints in the output window. I then decided to try programmatically, and I'm still getting the error.

The code snippet below shows one of several solutions that I've tried.

```
class MapThumbnail: UIView {

    let contentView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        initialize()
    }

    func initialize() {

        addSubview(contentView)

        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 4.0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8.0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 4.0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8.0).active = true

    }


}
```

Here is the output that I'm receiving:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>       Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
>   (
>       "",
>       ""
>   )
>   Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
>   The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

Based on the solutions posted on StackOverflow and the above output, it seems that additional constraints are being added automatically (some of which conflict with my 4 constraints) because of auto layout masks.

However, as recommended, I set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and I'm still receiving these conflicts.

Comment: Are you sure it's this subview, and not the thumbnail view itself (or something else)? I'd try commenting out this code that adds the `contentView` and see if you still receive the error.

Comment: Hi @Rob, if I don't add the contentView to the view hierarchy, I get a runtime exception because I can't place a constraint on a view that isn't there.

Comment: An alternative that I tried that works is to replace the width and height constraints with positional constraints relative to the right and bottom margins. This works fine if the offset value is positive (but doesn't display properly) but it fails with a negative offset value (but displays what I want).

Comment: It works for me regardless of whether I use your above constraints, or replace `.Width` and `.Height` constraints with `.Trailing` and `.Bottom`. It must depend upon something not provided here (e.g. how `MapThumbnail` was added). Personally, I always use the `addConstraint(constraint)` method rather than `constraint.active = true`. And I wouldn't use a method called `initialize` (too easily confused with class method of the same name). But I don't think either of those affect your issue. Bottom line, I cannot reproduce your problem with the code provided, so it's hard to help you.